# Chromecast returns receiver_unavailable

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I want to use my own Custom Receiver along with my Chrome Sender. But when I try to set up an connection chrome.cast.requestSession always returns

```
{code: "receiver_unavailable", description: null, details: null}
```

The Receiver App is definitely available at the provided URL from the Chromecast Developer Console. The App has not been published yet, but if I am not wrong, it does not need to be published during developing process.

I already waited more than 6 hours to make sure the Receiver URL is propagated to the device as mentioned on the developers pages. And I even resetted my Chromecast.

I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your chromecast serial number, either take a photo and zoom in to read it that way (hard to distinguish O from 0, etc) or use the developer console to show or listen to the serial number on chromecast itself
2. Reboot your chromecast

If problem still persists, please contact our [support](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1) for getting further help.

P.S. please update the title to receiver_unavaliable rather than sender_unavailable

Comment: A wrong letter in the serial number. That's it, thank you!